# Tomboy cannot synchronize since updated to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, tomboy

I have an annoying problem. Since I've updated my ubuntu installation to 11.10, I cannot synchronize my notes in Tomboy anymore. I'm logged in into u1 notes, and when synchronizing it states that it failed without giving any further explanation. I tried to set up my sync preferences anew, but same results.

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the https address in the UbuntuOne parameters from `https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/` to `https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/notes/`.

See the online Ubuntu online documentation for UbuntuOne installation.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to instruction, or tell us how to change UbuntuOne parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it.

Preferences > Editing > Open New Note Template, change title "New Note Template" to something else, e.g. "Template".

This worked for me.

Thanks to this [instructions](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=109&t=91780).